# How to only execute the first test in a Test class with TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I'm putting together a navigation test suite to exercise a little bit of functionality on each page of my company's internal application with Java / Selenium / TestNG.

Say I have a test class called ApplicationsIT in my NavigationTests directory.  Within this class, I have 10 @Tests annotations so every time I run the full NavigationTests suite all 10 Tests run.

But, for the sake of time, is there a way for me to only run the first test in each test class?

I tried messing with the "(alwaysRun = false)" tags but it didn't seem to work how I'd expected.

I know this is a poorly constructed question/post so I'd be happy to clarify anything I can.

Comment: This is really a TestNG question and has nothing to do with Selenium. i would remove the tag lest it confuse others. Have you looked at the TestNG documentation? I'm sure it would describe at least one way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at-least two ways of doing this dynamically.

1. Using an implementation of `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer`. Here you basically implement the interface `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer` and within its `transform()` method, you inspect the incoming `testMethod` `java.lang.reflect.Method` object to check if its name matches with what you want to run or not run. You can specify the intent to run/not run a bunch of methods via a JVM argument. If there's a match, then you basically disable the test method via `annotation.setEnabled(false)` here `annotation` is of type `org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation`. You would need to wire in this listener via a service loader (or) using the `<listeners>` tag in your suite xml file. For more information on listeners in general, you can take a look my blog post [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/listen-to-what-i-have-to-say-about-testng-listeners/)
2. The other option is to make use of a beanshell. The below sample shows you how to use the beanshell. You can read more about how to work with beanshells, from my blog post [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/beanshell-and-testng/).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="47230879_Suite" parallel="false" verbose="2">
    <test name="47230879_test" verbose="2">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                    <![CDATA[
                        try {
                            input = System.getProperty("methods","");
                            if (input.trim().isEmpty()) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            methods= input.split(",");
                            for (int i =0; i< methods.length; i++) {
                                if (method.getName().equals(methods[i])) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                        } catch( e ) {
                            print(e);
                        }
                    ]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn47230879.TestclassSample"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The test class looks like below

```java
package com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn47230879;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestclassSample {
    @Test
    public void a() {
        System.err.println("a()");
    }

    @Test
    public void b() {
        System.err.println("b()");
    }

    @Test
    public void c() {
        System.err.println("c()");
    }

    @Test
    public void d() {
        System.err.println("d()");
    }

    @Test
    public void e() {
        System.err.println("e()");
    }
}
```

If you run the suite without specifying any methods via JVM arguments, all methods get run, but if you specify a bunch of method names via JVM argument `-Dmethods=a,b,c` (for e.g.,) then only those methods get executed.